# SELECT WHERE IN null

Tags: mysql, select

Can a SELECT statement use an IN clause to find null values?

For example:

```
SELECT 
  `TEST`,
  `TEST2`,
  `TEST3`
FROM
  table
WHERE `TEST3` IN ('var1','var2', null)
```

I need to bring back all records whether they are null or not.

I am not getting any errors, but I am not returning any null values.

How do I make this work?

Comment: ... and `null` is not a value, not even the absence of a value, but more like "undefined".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use an `OR` operator:

```
SELECT 
  `TEST`,
  `TEST2`,
  `TEST3`
FROM
  table
WHERE `TEST3` IN ('var1','var2') or `TEST3` is null
```